# Where does Jenkins store the project source

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that uses a script to build my project. On the following line, the script fails `mvn -e -X -Dgit='$git' release:prepare`.

Because I want to search for the cause of this, I want to go to the Jenkins server and run `mvn -e -X -Dgit='$git' release:prepare` from the command line, to see if it works.

Does Jenkins store the projects' source code somewhere, such that I can go to that folder and call Maven?

If yes, then where?

Comment: yes it stores the sourcecode in workspaces

Answer (score 7):

Yes, It Stores the project files for the job by default at

> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/{your-job-name}

This is where jenkins suppose the project files to be present or it pulls it from a source before start working/building from it.

Comment: If concurrent builds happen , jenkins creates directories like {job-name}@tmp , {job-name}@2@tmp and so on for additional builds that are triggered while another build of the same job is already running.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Andrew M.:

"Hudson/Jenkins doesn't quite work that way. It stores configurations and job information in /var/lib/jenkins by default (if you're using the .deb package). If you want to setup persistence for a specific application, that's something you'll want to handle yourself - Hudson is a [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server, not a test framework.

Check out the Wiki article on Continuous Integration for an overview of what to expect."

From this [Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/232866/where-and-how-does-hudson-jenkins-store-data) on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`/var/jenkins/workspace/JobNameExample`

**but**, if your build machine (node) is a different than the one where Jenkins is running (manager), You need specify it:

`/var/jenkins/workspace/JobNameExample/label/NodeName`

Where you can define `label` too:

[image: if connected to a node]

Answer (score 0):

jenkins stores its workspace files currently in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name
I am running from docker though!

Comment: This answer was already given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42672199/5468463